# Can't browse internet from browser after connecting to VPN. Skype still works

Tags: macos, network, vpn

I am connecting my office VPN using Cisco AnyConnect. After connecting to VPN I can't connect to internet from browsers. However, skype still works. How to resolve ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to change your DNS of the connected network to the internet for the following Google's IP.

```
8.8.8.8 
8.8.4.4
```

[image]

If this didn't help, then I guess it is also due to your office IT policy.